# Python requests, Loading in AJAX content

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all the 'AVAILABLE VACANCIES' from the URL `https://careers.sega.co.uk/vacancies?f%5B0%5D=country%3AUnited%20Kingdom`

I've written the following code:

```
import requests

def SEGA():

    data = []
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Referer': 'https://careers.sega.co.uk/vacancies?f%5B0%5D=country%3AUnited%20Kingdom'
    }
    url = "https://careers.sega.co.uk/vacancies?f%5B0%5D=country%3AUnited%20Kingdom"
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    xpath = '//*[@id="content"]/section/div/div/div[*]/div[*]/div[*]/h3/a/text()'
    jobs = tree.xpath(xpath)
    for job in jobs:
        Title = (job)
        Location = "Brentford"
        Studio = "SEGA"
        data.append([Title,Location,Studio])
    return data
```

This returns the first 25 roles while when loading the page should have 62. I'm struggling to get the content to load using requests. Not sure how to get the AJAX to load all content.

Comment: The page only loads the first 25 initially. You'd need to change the search options and then click Find. But you won't be able to do that via the requests library. Instead: Open the page; open up the browser's developer console; switch to the network tab; set the filters for Ajax, XHR, or fetch; in the page, switch to Items per page: All; click Find; look at the network tab again and find a likely url that contains your data. The response will be in JSON which is easier to process.

Comment: So I tried that and the only page that comes up is `https://apikeys.civiccomputing.com/c/v?d=careers.sega.co.uk&p=CookieControl%20Multi-Site&v=9&k=6dc1b7a8c8fe9deaa2ae1a45a52549891454d684&format=json` and that returns nothing of value. I also tried to load data with the find button and the pages returned wher https://careers.sega.co.uk/facets-block-ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax which have nothing of value either

Comment: Yup. You'll need more than just the url. It'll have a different method (POST), and it'll have a request body that contains the full query, also in json. You can click on the url in the network tab and it'll show these various information.

Comment: Are you sure you did it right? Followed all the steps in the right order? For me, three urls came up. The important one starts with `https://careers.sega.co.uk/views/ajax?...`

Comment: yeah I followed it in the browser the url `https://careers.sega.co.uk/views/ajax?..` and wrote some quick code `url = "https://careers.sega.co.uk/views/ajax?f%5B0%5D=country%3AUnited%20Kingdom&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax"` 
`page = requests.post(url)`
`tree = html.fromstring(page.content)`
`print(tree.text)`

and got this response `{"message":""}`

Comment: As I said, you also need to use the request body which contains the query.

Comment: If nothing works, you could manually click the show all button using an automated browser like selenium to find the rest of the results.

Comment: @walker That's an interesting suggestion, how would I approch that? never used selium.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json

uri = r'https://careers.sega.co.uk/views/ajax?f[0]=country%3AUnited%20Kingdom&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax'

formdata = r'search=&sort_by=search_api_relevance&items_per_page=All&view_name=jobs&view_display_id=page&view_args=&view_path=%2Fvacancies&view_base_path=vacancies&view_dom_id=fb1a232671720353ae08be0eb4a72fccadb593119768c5f1f3ef208cbac1be50&pager_element=0&_drupal_ajax=1&ajax_page_state%5Btheme%5D=careers&ajax_page_state%5Btheme_token%5D=&ajax_page_state%5Blibraries%5D=bootstrap_barrio%2Fform%2Cbootstrap_barrio%2Fglobal-styling%2Cbootstrap_barrio%2Fmessages_light%2Ccareers%2Fglobal-styling%2Ccareers%2Fswiper%2Ccareers%2Fyoutube-api%2Ccareers_civic%2Fcareers-civic%2Ccareers_civic%2Fcivic%2Cfacets%2Fdrupal.facets.link-widget%2Cfacets%2Fdrupal.facets.views-ajax%2Clazy%2Flazy%2Cparagraphs%2Fdrupal.paragraphs.unpublished%2Csearch_api_autocomplete%2Fsearch_api_autocomplete%2Csystem%2Fbase%2Cviews%2Fviews.ajax%2Cviews%2Fviews.module'

headers = {
    'Accept' : 'text/javascript',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

response = requests.post(uri, data=formdata, headers=headers)

data = json.loads(response.text)

html = [command for command in data if 'data' in command][0]['data']
```

Looks like, in this case, you still need to handle html, but it does include all entries.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? I ran it and got the error `'list' object has no attribute 'html' `. I also looped through the list and none of the values I am looking for are there

Comment: It worked for me shortly after writing it. But consider that there is absolutely no error checking here. Also, The server might very well respond differently in different situations or certain data in the query evolves over time (e.g.: `view_dom_id`). Often there are also preventative measures in place since most sites don't want people scraping their data.